# jquery date validation on multiple fields

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I am attempting to use jquery to validate a date that is broken up into MM DD YYYY fields.

```
<form name="dateform" id="dateform">
<input type="text" name="month"/>
<input type="text" name="day"/>
<input type="text" name="year"/>
</form>
```

I can only find [examples](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/date) that use a single field, which is not what I want.

```
<form name="dateform" id="dateform">
<input type="text" name="date"/>
</form>
```

Any examples I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

You might try assembling your individual fields into a javascript date object.

```
var $form = $('form#dateform');
var dateToCheck = new Date( 
   $form.find('input[name=year]').val(), 
   $form.find('input[name=month]').val(),
   $form.find('input[name=day]').val() );
```

Then apply whatever validation you need to `dateToCheck`. If you'd like to use the validate plugin, one approach would be to store/update the assembled full date in a hidden field, and validate that field.